# Android FragmentTabHost - No tab known for tag "articulos"

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, host

I'm making a FragmentTabHost (extended by FragmentActivity).

I'm trying to set up the tab bar but I have an error called `No tab known for tag articulos`.

This is my java file:

```
public class TabHostActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private String mCurrenTab;
    private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
                android.R.id.tabcontent);

        inicializarTabs();

    }

    public void inicializarTabs() {

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("articulos");
        spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator("Articulos");
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


    }

    public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment,
            boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAdd) {
        if (shouldAdd) {
            mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
        }
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

So, when I run the app it shows me this error:

[image]

I think i need to set the `Articulos class` to that tab? But i don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
public void inicializarTabs() {

    tabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("articulos").setIndicator("Articulos"), Articulos.class, null);


 }
```